# How to get the MK fight stick (xbox 360 version) to work on PS3?

Tags: mortal-kombat-9

Here is my model: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004XNYVGO/ref=s9_simh_gw_p63_d0_i3?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=19XSHXMEYHPA28NCGGD7&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1389517282&pf_rd_i=507846](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004XNYVGO)

Obviously, this isn't possible out of the box.

I wanted to know if this was actually doable. If so, how?

I've read online about different options like modding it. This is one of the really expensive MK fight stick models and I really don't want to mod it and change things around and take the risk of screwing it up.

I've seen items like this: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0089OBLDO/ref=s9_simh_gw_p63_d0_i1?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=center-4&pf_rd_r=09GE1CMEMC08YP5DH2RY&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=470939031&pf_rd_i=507846](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0089OBLDO)

I don't know reliable these things are since I've never tried or used them.

Comment: You've answered your own question; it's not possible out of the box.  If you're asking how to GET it working for PS3, that might be something we can answer.

Comment: @fbueckert changed it

Answer (score 0):

You'll simply either need an adapter (as you've linked) that takes 360 input and outputs it in PS3 format, or a Printed Circuit Board (PCB) to install into the stick to allow it to output in multiple formats. Which is better depends on whether you want to keep the stick and whether you want to mod the stick.

Note many arcade sticks are fairly modification friendly and many competitive fighting game players mod their sticks as Sanwa (for example) buttons/sticks are higher quality than stock parts. Note you'll probably void your warranty by cracking it open of course; there's usually the little "void if broken" stickers around the casing.

If you don't plan to keep the stick forever, the adapter is more versatile for multiple sticks. If you plan to keep the stick forever and use it on many consoles, you'll want a PCB. [The Cthulhu](http://www.focusattack.com/toodles-cthulhu-multi-console-pcb/) is more or less the standard for multi-console sticks, and on that page you'll find plenty of resources for installing the PCB and cable. The only real limitation of the Cthulhu is it's not designed for the upcoming PS4/Xbox One consoles (Or wii U best I'm aware).

I don't know as much about adapters; you'll just have to buy one you trust and/or use a shop with a return policy in case it doesn't work. But the adapter should be more or less plug and play. Just know the adapter's limitations beforehand.